# tunnel in python script with execution of python command

Tags: python, ssh-tunneling

I want to login to different host and get want to execute the below python script

```
isi storagepool list -v |
awk ' /Requested Protection:/ { parity=substr($NF,length($NF)-1,1) }
    /Nodes:/ { nodes=$NF }
    /HDD Total/ { hdd_total=$NF }
    /HDD Used/ { hdd_used=$NF }
    END {
        multiplier=nodes-parity
        total=hdd_total/nodes*multiplier
        used=hdd_used/nodes
        print "parity =" parity
        print "NodeNumber =" nodes
        print "Total = " total " TB"
        print "Effective Total volume = " total*0.8 " TB"
        print "USED =" used                          
        print "Effective used=" used*multiplier*0.8 " TB" 
        print "Available volume=" (hdd_total-hdd_used)/nodes*multiplier*0.8 " TB" }'
```

in the below tunnel script instead of isi storagepool list command, we want to run the above command. we are not looking for exec_command the `python.py` script, because we can't create any file on storage host.

```
import paramiko
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('jump_host_ip', 222),
    ssh_username="User.name",
    ssh_pkey=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/tmp/id_rsa"),
  #  ssh_private_key_password="user_pass",
    remote_bind_address=("host_ip", 22),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 10022)
) as tunnel:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
#   client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1', username='user.name, password='user_pass', port=10022)
#   client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10022)
    # do some operations with client session
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sshpass -p  ******* ssh root@Storage_host_ip "isi storagepool list"')
    print stdout.readlines()
    print stderr.readlines()
    client.close()

print('FINISH!')`
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I want to create a tunnel to get into the jumphost and then again run a ssh to a server and then run the awk command which gives the output